# JOGL VBO, alternatives to glDrawElements

Tags: opengl, vbo, indices

I'm running the following code during the render

```
if (fUseVBO) {
            gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOTexCoords[0]);
            // Set The TexCoord Pointer To The TexCoord Buffer
            gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
            gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOVertices[0]);
            // Set The Vertex Pointer To The Vertex Buffer
            gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
        } else {
            // Specifies the location and data format of an array of vertex
            // coordinates to use when rendering.
            gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, mVerticesBuffer);
            // Set The Vertex Pointer To Our TexCoord Data
            gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, mTextureBuffer);
        }

        gl.glDrawElements(GL.GL_TRIANGLES, mNumOfIndices,
                        GL.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mIndicesBuffer);
```

In this method even tough I have VBO for texture coordinates and for vertices, I'm passing the indices buffer every time I render. (I have vertices, texture coordinates and indices for an object)

I tried to replace the gl.glDrawElements method with the following code

```
gl.glDrawArrays(GL.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);
```

but it did not rendered the objects properly.

How to get rid of glDrawElements ?

Comment: My mistake
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);
must be changed to
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, mNumOfIndices);
Now it works

Comment: FYI, it is better to post your own solution as an answer, instead of a question edit. Otherwise the question forever appears to be unanswered.

Comment: @Dnu_12 You'll also get 15 rep even if you answer your own question

Answer (score 3):

This code

```
gl.glDrawArrays(GL.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);
```

must be changed to

```
gl.glDrawArrays(GL.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, mNumOfIndices);
```

(courtesy of Dnu_12)